# How to implement microservices in django and make them communicate with one another

Tags: django, build, microservices

I'am new with the framework **django** and I want to realize a project using **microservices**.

I have been looking for detailed documentation about but til now I've found nothing
very helpful and which explains the procedure step by step. Different microservices must be able to **communicate with one another**.

I've already tried django microservices explain by **Pypi** but no good results.
So if someoene can help me with the procedure or templates for microservices I'll be grateful.

*PS. My OS is windows7 64bits and I can't use docker on it.*

Thank you for your help...

Comment: This isn't a question. Microseconds isn't something you install from PyPI, and it's not a procedure or template. What are you actually asking?

Comment: So how can I set up a project with microservices in django?